# How to distinguish between local filesystem path and file system path over SSH?

Tags: python, regex

In Python on Linux, I need to distinguish between local filesystem paths à la `/mnt/data/wherever/%Y-%m-%d.txt` or `~/data/bla.txt` on the one hand, and SSH "paths" à la `user@host1:/data/bla.txt` or `user@host2.mydomain.com:blupp.txt`.

How can I efficiently do that?

**EDIT:** In my example, there is no file `/mnt/data/wherever/%Y-%m-%d.txt`, because the `%Y` etc are merely placeholders. So checking if a file/directory with the given name exists won't work.

Comment: the "@" and ":" are a good start. Also in your second "SSH" path you may need to implement some logic about getting the HOME directory correctly (/root/ for root, /home/user/ for user). However, there is no way to be really sure, as user@host1 is a valid directory name.

Comment: on all systems I've been on so far, `user@host2.mydomain.com:blupp.txt` would point to `user@host2.mydomain.com:/home/user/blupp.txt` (or wherever the user's `$HOME` is located). So I wouldn't care about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know is to use a heuristic, as the ssh paths are also valid filenames (although very weird ones).

From the scp documentation:

> File names may contain a user and host specification to indicate that 
>   the file is to be copied to/from that host. Local file names can be made 
>   explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file 
>   names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.

So check if they start as an explicit path, or don't have a colon in them in the right place. Then assume it's a local path, otherwise assume it's a remote path.

Example:

```
pattern = '(\.?/|/)|(^:?[^:]*$)'
re.match(pattern, ":home/test") # match, is a local path
re.match(pattern, "user@host:blah") # no match
```

Comment: You could also assume user@host is a ssh path and not a local path (I believe scp and ssh differ slightly on whether they interpret it as local). Would need to change the regex a little bit, possibly just do a separate check for this simple case.

Comment: In your example, the expression you check against is not the same in both cases. This confuses me, because how should I know when to use which expression?

Comment: @andreas-h sorry I changed the regex because a colon at the end should probably be interpreted as a ssh path, but forgot to change the query. They should just both be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this -

1. First check in local filesystem a path X (this accounts for paths like - `user@host1:/data/bla.txt`).
2. If the path X does not exist in local filesystem, then check for `SSH` path Y (with additional checks for "@" and ":" since otherwise that file it not present in any machine).

Use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) to list file based on a pattern.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('/mnt/data/wherever/*.txt')   # all txt files within the directory will be listed
```

[`os.path.isfile(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) returns `True` if a path is an existing regular file. So that is used for checking whether a file already exists and doesn't support wildcards. `glob` does.
To check if a path is an existing file in local filesystem use :

Comment: as I can have placeholders in the string indicating the path, there might not be a file with the exact path of the string. see my edit to the question.

Comment: then `glob` is what you need. python `glob` supports regular expressions. So you can still check if the file exists or not.